# How to select first label within div using css?

Tags: html, css

Hi i want to select first label element within div with classname form_fields.

Below is the code,

```
 <form>
     <div className="form_fields">
         <span>first span</span>
         <div>first div</div>
         <label>
             <span>Name</span>
         </label>
         <label>Description</label>
     </div></form>
```

What i have tried?

```
.fields label:first-child {
    margin: 20px;
}
```

But this doesnt apply to the first label inside div of class form_fields. How can i do it? thanks.

Comment: You can't use className in inline html. Use class instead. Also make sure the class is the same as the one you are using in the css. `:first-child` selects the first child of label. See answers below for the correct way.

Comment: I’d say this is a mis-use of the `label` element to begin with … you should rather start by fixing the HTML (if that is an option.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with [`first-of-type`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssreF/sel_first-of-type.asp) pseudo-selector:

```
.form_fields label:first-of-type {
    margin: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.form_fields label:nth-of-type(1) {
    margin: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can imagine you are looking to do more than just that but its a great start to ask around here. In HTML and CSS you will find there are several ways to achieve the same results and the path you choose will often be based on personal preferences. In this specific case you have just concept mistakes but you are definitively on the right track.

1. in your  tag, you should change className o just "class".
2. in your style, change :first-child to :first-of-type

```
<form>
  <div class="form_fields">
    <span>first span</span>
    <div>first div</div>
    <label>
      <span>Name</span>
    </label>
    <label>Description</label>
  </div>
</form>

<style>
  .form_fields label:first-of-type {
    margin: 20px;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can choose between 2 pseudo-class :

- The `:first-of-type` CSS pseudo-class represents the first element of its type among a group of sibling elements. [See doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type)
- The `:nth-of-type(1)` CSS pseudo-class matches elements of a given type, based on their position among a group of siblings. [See doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)

## Solution with `:first-of-type` :

[image]

```css
.form_fields label:first-of-type {
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="form_fields">
    <span>first span</span>
    <div>first div</div>
    <label>
      <span>Name</span>
    </label>
    <label>Description</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.form_fields label:nth-of-type(1) {
     color: blue;
 }
```